# Word for "repeat giver" or "repeat giving"?

Tags: single-word-requests

My clergyman asked me whether there exists a single word for a person or thing "that keeps on giving," that is, gives over and over again.  I couldn't come up with such a word, but I volunteered the spontaneous coinages, "palindoric" or "palindotic" (for the adjectives, obviously).  Can anyone suggest a better word or coinage? Thank you.

POSTSCRIPTUM:  I should probably clarify a bit more:  he wanted the word to be value-neutral, one that could cover equally sinning and blessing, for example, or a long-deceased beloved grandparent and an abusive ex-spouse.  The idea behind this, I suppose, is that some events and persons in our lives can be reverberative either positively or negatively:  they continue to 'give' to us in some sense regardless of whether we want to accept.

Comment: What about *generous*: willing and liberal in giving away one's money, time, etc; munificent.

Comment: Possibly: *ATM*.

Comment: Not a single word, but in the world of university advancement, such a person is affectionately known as "a live one."

Comment: "Bottomless well"?

Comment: I'd question the advisability of attempting to use the same word for both a generous, righteous person and a stingy abuser.

Comment: My clergyman is in his 80s, quite venerable, and thoroughly compos mentis. I'm really rather loath to question him on any ground!

Comment: Your own suggestion based on the word *reverberate* conveys the concept well - consequences that last a long time but that are felt in bursts rather than continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would like "fount".

> [fount](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fount) - A source of a desirable quality or commodity.

It should be a familiar word to a clergyman because of the hymn "Come Thou Fount of Every Blessing".

Answer (score 0):

How about "**cornucopian**"?  A cornucopia, literally meaning "horn of plenty", is a mythical object that could produce as much food as was desired, or, in some tellings, anything that was desired.  The word is defined by Merriam-Webster as "an inexhaustible store".